# Flood effect to change text colour in Flash / Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

I'm guessing that this post will hit a different group of people who seem to usually end up  helping on my normal quest of trying to understand PHP and MySQL... Having partly understood some of the stuff that people have helped me out with, I'm now moving on to Flash and Actionscript (with absolutely no knowledge whatsoever).

I've managed to get some words to fly across the screen using motion tweens (I think) - which I have to say I actually impressed myself in doing so, but what I would now like to be able to do is, when the words have all come to a stop, I'd like each word to 'morph' into a different colour - so when they fly in, they're all blue, and then when they've all stopped (and each word is a different layer) the first word changes to say red, the next to green and so on....

I'd just like people's thoughts on how I might be able to do this, and what great effects I might be able to acomplish in doing so.

Many Thanks in advance.

Rob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have used motion tweens on flash's timeline to let the letters fly in, you could also use the timeline's effects to change the color.

a different way would be the to tween only with actionscript - one of the easiest ways to tween a movieclip/sprite is using a tween-engine (i like [tweenlite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/)).
tweenlite also has a ["timeline version"](http://www.greensock.com/timelinelite/) which lets you customize you tweening a bit better ...

with this plugin ([splittextfield](http://www.greensock.com/splittextfield/)), you can also tween each letter in a string.

there are also many tutorials on the site - just watch/read through them and you'll catch on real quick.

hope this helps you a bit...

Comment: Many thanks, that'll give me a great starting point. Thank you.